# Why do Rich text boxes appear as plain text boxes on some PCs?

Tags: 2007

We run SharePoint 2007. Some PCs, when displaying pages to be edited within SharePoint display the Rich text boxes as simple text boxes. The text is shown in a plain font with HTML commands embedded as text rather than as text of different colours, fonts, boldness etc.

Is there any reason for this? I have checked through the Internet explorer settings and cannot see anything different between PCs which do this and those which show the text boxes as rich ones with the HTML editor toolbar at the top.

All of our client PCs use Windows 7 Pro and some use IE8 & some use IE9. I have tried both IE's on a PC and changing this makes no difference.

Thanks,

Les